# Kivy - ImportError: dlopen failed: "../sklearn/.../__check_build.so is" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, kivy, buildozer

I am using kivy module to transform a python code into mobile application but facing same error since I want to import CountVectorizer method from sklearn library.

I need to use that library but I get `__check_build.so is 64-bit instead of 32-bit` error and then says `It seems scikit-learn has not been built yet...`. I couldn't find any solution on the Internet.

I use a virtual machine with 64-bit Linux Ubuntu.

Here is my [log](https://mega.nz/file/MooW2RZR#jYDygH2OtzE7_B6MJqQA0XY3tbMS7obWi8XJeZuDw9k) file from logcat command and [bulldozer.spec](https://mega.nz/file/d8hQCDTb#yA5VOeqq1zlKEHUOcUG_Nxi5VSnpMKHw6Nt9uRS7SNM) file.

---

Any help would be appreciated.